# How to change primeng library in sharedModules angular

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

so i have a shared module [image of shared module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uaqq.png)

and i created a folder,with the custom library css that i made so i can direct it in the angular.js,so far so good, but the library has some text in their component and i want to change the languague, i also have the component.js.map files, how do i direct does maps son when angular build them with the ng serve i can see my changes reflected ?

i already try to import the libary to my shared module, so i can make changes there directly and it didnt work

Comment: did you check this [link](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/setup) ?

Answer (score 0):

so, actually, there was a simple solution, primeng has an i18n support feature, you can do it through [enter link description here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/i18n)